# Hide multiple child-category from displaying on category page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I would like to hide multiple child-categories (CAT1, CAT2) from displaying on the main category page in woocommerce. I have found some code that works for this.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'exclude_category', 10, 3 );
function exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if( is_object ( $term ) ) {
                if ( 'CAT1' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
                elseif ( 'CAT2' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

But the only way it works if I create a new "elseif" line for every category that i want to hide.
Is there a way to chain these two together?

```
            if ( 'CAT1' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                unset($terms[$key]);
            }
            elseif ( 'CAT2' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                unset($terms[$key]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `in_array()`, store terms you want to unset in `$exclude_terms` and pass that in `in_array($term->slug, $exclude_terms)`. Here is the complete code:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'exclude_category', 10, 3 );
function exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $exclude_terms = array('CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3');

    if ( is_product_category() ){
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if( is_object ( $term ) ) {
                if ( in_array($term->slug, $exclude_terms) && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```